# Regex - How to make sure only 1 instance of character occuring between two characters or from start to certain character

Tags: java, regex

I want to make sure only 1 instance of comoa occurs before parenthesis.  Parenthesis is a must.   I need to make sure all string matches the pattern. Regex matcher must not substring.

Examples;

```
 Mert,sert , abc() = not valid
 Mert, asd( = valid
 Mert , asd,( = not valid
 Mert , asd = not valid
```

I tried this one and also can you explain why it did not work? Thanks

```
.+,[^,]+\(.+
```

Comment: Try `"^[^,(]*\\(.*"`

Comment: @Aaron if i do that, then it does not get all the string in the search. It substrings after second comoa. I need to make sure all string matches the pattern

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i am trying here and it does not work. ( removed second escape) https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: I forgot the anchor. `^[^,]*,[^,]*\(` ; tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/sZhrSU/1)

Comment: @Aaron can you explain part by part? Thanks. You can post it as main comment.

Comment: From the start of a string (`^`), match any character but a comma (`[^,]`) any number of time including 0 (`*`), then a comma, then any character but a comma any number of time including 0, then an open parenthesis. Not sure making an answer out of it would be a good idea, I'm sure there is a duplicate of the generic question you're asking somewhere on here. I'll see if I can find it

Comment: @Aaron The expression you suggest does not account for parenthesis, it will match `Mert(, asd(`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZxslh/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it still make sure there's only one instance comma before that second parenthesis it matches, but I agree your answer is probably closer to what OP needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^,(]*,[^,(]*\(.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jnfc6q/1)

In Java, use

```
Boolean result = s.matches("[^,(]*,[^,(]*\\(.*");
```

Or, if there can be line breaks, `s.matches("(?s)[^,(]*,[^,(]*\\(.*")`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (it is not necessary in `String#matches`)
- `[^,(]*` - 0 or more chars other than a comma and open parenthesis
- `,` - a comma
- `[^,(]*` - 0 or more chars other than a comma and open parenthesis
- `\(` - an open parenthesis
- `.*` - the rest of the line / string (with `(?s)`).